# How do I convert a list to an integer?

Tags: python

This my code:

```
snumA = random.sample([4,8,3], 1)
snumB = random.sample([7,2,6], 1)
snumC = random.sample([1,5,9], 1)

sgnA = random.choice(['+','-','/','*'])
sgnB = random.choice(['+','-','/','*'])
sgnC = random.choice(['+','-','/','*'])

if sgnA == '-' :
    sum1 = snumA - bnumA
    print 'minus'
if sgnA == '/' :
    sum1 = snumA / bnumA
    print 'divide'
```

Whenever I run this code I get an error message telling me that my operands are lists and not integers. I've looked everywhere and  I still don't know what to do. Could I have some help, please?

Comment: `random.sample` gives you a list. Maybe you wanted `random.choice`.

Answer (score 4):

Change to :

```
snumA = random.choice([4,8,3])
```

which will give you an `int` instead of a `list`. To understand better the error here is that you try to use lists (cause `random.sample` returns a list type result) as integers to make arithmetic operations which is false.
On the other hand `random.choice` does what you want but returns an `int`
type result - so you won't get an error.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is: `snumA = random.sample([4,8,3], 1)` returns a list of one element (for example: [3] ). What you can do instead is:
Either use `snumA = random.choice([4,8,3])` which returns directly an integer. Or you get hold of the first element of your list with `snumA[0]` or directly `snumA = random.sample([4,8,3], 1)[0]`

Answer (score 1):

1. As suggested before, use random.choice
2. bnumA is not defined. The code below assumes you meant snumB

So the code you are looking for might be:

```
import random

snumA = random.choice([4,8,3])
snumB = random.choice([7,2,6])
snumC = random.choice([1,5,9])

operators = {'+':'Plus', '-':'Minus', '/':'Division','*':'Multiplication'}
sgnA = random.choice(list(operators.keys()))
sgnB = random.choice(list(operators.keys()))
sgnC = random.choice(list(operators.keys()))

print(eval(str(snumA)+sgnA+str(snumB)))
print(operators[sgnA])
```